# Conflicting data in ATmega32u2 datasheet: PLLCSR PLL Control and Status Register

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, datasheet

I'm trying to make a simple USB breakout board based on the ATmega32u2 and I've come across some conflicting information in the datasheet. Can somebody with experience confirm or deny what is said in this datasheet?

It states that two bits in the register PLLCSR are read-only and reserved (bit 3:2), but one is needed to setup the USB clock by writing to it (PINDIV, for USB with 16 MHz crystal). Both statements can't be true, unless these bits are special somehow.

[image: raster image of PLLCSR bit 7-2 description]
(So far it may be a numbering mishap, but the next page continues:)

> **• Bit 1 – PLLE: PLL Enable**
> When the PLLE is set, the PLL is started. Note that the Calibrated 8 MHz Internal RC oscillator is
> automatically enabled when the PLLE bit is set and with PINMUX (see PLLFRQ register) is set.
> The PLL must be disabled before entering Power down mode in order to stop Internal RC Oscillator and avoid extra-consumption.
> **• Bit 0 – PLOCK: PLL Lock Detector**
> When the PLOCK bit is set, the PLL is locked to the reference clock. After the PLL is enabled, it
> takes about several ms for the PLL to lock. To clear PLOCK, clear PLLE.

This isn't a huge problem right now, as I'm currently using its default value, but I was going to include a 16 MHz crystal in a later build, if it is actually possible. The datasheet does talk about that configuration being valid, so I wasn't expecting to see bit access like this. This is the link to the datasheet, https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATMEGA32U2

Comment: Please add a link of the datasheet as well

Comment: I added the link

Comment: Writing control register sets multiplier. Reading status register the bits are reserved and read as 0. No conflict.

Comment: @daannn, PINDIV has to be R/W because it is needed to be written for USB setup as you say. I seriously doubt whether DIV5 is R/W. Looks like DIV5 & DIV3 are the read-only bits that are reserved and the datasheet is all messed up in this regard. You can write 111 in DIV5,DIV3,PINDIV and read it back to confirm if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, DIV3 and PINDIV are both read/write. I ran the following code and I lit up an LED.

```
PLLCSR |= (1 << 3) | (1 << 2);
if(PLLCSR & 0b00001100)
led.setBit(); //light up led
```

Edit: This code shows whether either bit is set not both.  But I changed it slightly and ran it twice, once on each bit.  They both respond with the led lighting up.

Answer (score 0):

That is clearly an error in the data sheet. The two bits of that register are defined and explained twice, so both cannot be true at the same time.